# Angular, Express & http-proxy-middleware. How to reach remote server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, http-proxy-middleware

I'm building MEAN stack app, so I have at backend node+express server, Angular on front.

Atm I need to reach a remote non-cors server with data by sending a POST request to it. Googled for a day, and understand that I need to establish a proxy middleware. Trying to use this on backend server:

```
app.use(
  "/getPrice",
createProxyMiddleware({
    target: someurl,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
      proxyReq.setHeader("X-DV-Auth-Token", sometoken);
      proxyReq.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      proxyReq.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      req.body = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    },
  })
);
```

But request didn't return anything.
On other hand trying same url, payload and headers from PostMan, I have response with data exactly I need.

But PostMan offers only request-based solution which I can't adopt for using with express and http-proxy middleware

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': someurl,
  'headers': {
    'X-DV-Auth-Token': sometoken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': somecookie
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({requestBodyObject})

};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Please, point me, where I probably missing a bit, or suggest how to adopt PostMan's code into express & http-proxy solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Appending `req.body` in http-proxy should be done using `proxyReq.write(JSON.stringify(body))`.

So the modified `createProxyMiddleware`  function would be:

```
    app.use(
      "/getPrice",
       createProxyMiddleware({
          target: someurl,
          changeOrigin: true,
          logLevel: "debug",
          onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
            proxyReq.setHeader("X-DV-Auth-Token", sometoken);
            proxyReq.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            proxyReq.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            console.log(req.body);
            if (req.body) {
              let bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
              // stream the content
              proxyReq.write(bodyData);
           }
        },
      })
    );
```

Also, before you try the above changes, please make sure if you are receiving data in `req.body` or not.

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately got no response

Comment: Were you able to view your req.body in the console?

Comment: using this solution - yes, I can. 
Also, revoking question, solved this query via dedicated routes and using internal async functions inside controller.